# Changing program from using threads to using fork

Tags: c, unix, pthreads, fork

I am learning to use forks. The task was to create simulation of warehouse's work. Producers (in an amount of argv[2])  create random number of "goods" (totally argv[1]), and consumers (in an amount of argv[3]) get random number of these goods. Below is the code for the program using threads. But I am trying to do the same using related proccesses (using fork()). 2nd version of the program doesn't work at all. Producers create 0 goods. I don't understand how to use fork properly. Should I somehow kill childs? Do they kill themselves after returning or continue to work till the end? Please help me to fix the second program. 
Second program:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#define NBUFF 10
#define MAXNTHREADS 100
#define min( a, b ) ( ( a < b) ? a : b ) 
int nitems, nproducers, nconsumers; 

typedef struct shared_s
{ 
    int buff[NBUFF];
    int nput; 
    int nputval; 
    int nget;
    int ngetval; 
    sem_t mutex, nempty, nstored; 
} sharedtype;




int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    sharedtype * shared;
    key_t key;
    int shmid, semid;
    int i, j, prodcount[MAXNTHREADS], conscount[MAXNTHREADS];

    shared = mmap(NULL, sizeof(sharedtype),
                PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);

    /* Wrong argv */
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        printf("usage: newconsumer <#items> <#producers> <#consumers>\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    nitems = atoi(argv[1]);
    nproducers = min(atoi(argv[2]), MAXNTHREADS);
    nconsumers = min(atoi(argv[3]), MAXNTHREADS);
    pid_t chpidpr [nproducers];
    pid_t chpidcon [nconsumers];
    /* initilising semaphores */
    sem_init(&(shared->mutex), 0, 1);
    sem_init(&(shared->nempty), 0, NBUFF);
    sem_init(&(shared->nstored), 0, 0);


    for (i = 0; i < nproducers; i++) {
        prodcount[i] = 0;
        switch (chpidpr[i] = fork())
        {
            case -1: 
                printf("fork error"); 
                return 1;
            case 0: 
                for (;;) 
                {
                    sem_wait(&shared->nempty); 
                    sem_wait(&shared->mutex);
                    if (shared->nput >= nitems) 
                    {
                        sem_post(&(shared->nstored));
                        sem_post(&(shared->nempty));
                        sem_post(&(shared->mutex));
                        return 0; 
                    }
                    shared->buff[(shared->nput) %NBUFF] = shared->nputval;
                    (shared->nput)++;
                    (shared->nputval)++;
                    sem_post(&(shared->mutex));
                    sem_post(&(shared->nstored));
                    prodcount[i] += 1;
                }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < nproducers; i++) 
    {
        printf("producer count[%d] = %d\n", i, prodcount[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < nconsumers; i++) {
        conscount[i] = 0;
        switch (chpidcon[i] = fork())
        {
            case -1: 
                printf("error"); 
                return 1;
            case 0: 
                for (;;) 
                {
                    sem_wait(&(shared->nstored)); 
                    sem_wait(&(shared->mutex));
                    if (shared->nget >= nitems) 
                    {
                        sem_post(&(shared->nstored));
                        sem_post(&(shared->mutex));
                        return 0;
                    }
                    j = shared->nget % NBUFF;
                    if (shared->buff[j] != shared->ngetval)
                    {
                        printf("error: buff[%d] = %d\n", j, shared->buff[j]);
                    }
                    shared->nget++;
                    shared->ngetval++;
                    sem_post(&(shared->mutex));
                    sem_post(&(shared->nempty)); 
                    conscount[i] += 1;
                }
        }
    }


    for (i = 0; i < nconsumers; i++) 
    {
        printf("consumer count[%d] = %d\n", i, conscount[i]);
    }
    /* destroying semaphores */
    sem_destroy(&(shared->mutex));
    sem_destroy(&(shared->nempty));
    sem_destroy(&(shared->nstored));
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: I can't see that the second example uses pipes at all, as the title and question suggest. To use pipes, the producer processes would `write()` to the pipe when completing each product, and the main process would `read()` the results from the pipes when they're ready.

Comment: @Paul Griffiths my bad. I've made a program using pipes recently, so I  confused words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you could provide a minimal example of your code. So far the most obvious mistake that I can see is that your `struct {/* .. */} shared` is not in actual shared memory.

Threads have access to the same private memory, processes have their own private memory, that's why it's called private.

`fork()` creates cow copies of all memory that is not explicitly marked as shared. Allocate `shared` in shared memory would be the first thing to do.

`mmap/MAP_SHARED` is a good start for a program that creates new processes through `fork`.

```
struct shared_s {/* .. */} * shared;

int main() {
    shared = mmap(NULL, sizeof(struct shared_s)
                , PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
    // ....
}
```

Also in case you are working on OS X you need to pass an additional flag `MAP_HASSEMAPHORE` in order for your semaphores to work correctly.

Comment: Couldn't add MAP_HASSEMAPHORE, because it's not part of POSIX and I couldn't find it. 
However, I updated the code (in fact, not correctly, but I don't know what exactly is wrong) and got segmentation error.
UPDATE now I know what's wrong. Updating agn

Comment: @user3608127 `MAP_HASSEMAPHORE` is not POSIX and Linux does not have it, but it is required on OS X if you have semaphores in that mapping.

Comment: Got it! 
But segmentation error problem still exists and I couldn't find the cause.

Comment: @user3608127 You did not mention any segmentation errors in your question. Could you be more specific? Did you attach a debugger?

Comment: Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__new_sem_init (sem=0x37, pshared=0, value=1) at sem_init.c:44
44 sem_init.c: No such file or directory